# Powershell - from hash to string

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Need to resolve some problem... On teamcity, I received vcs build number as hash, f.e. 0630ad46ed0b297641151d64337faf3fc44078c8. In Powershell step I need to create version from this hash (substring first 8 symbols), but command 
`$version = %build.vcs.number.****` is invalid (it's the same if you tried to make command `$version = 0630ad46ed0b297641151d64337faf3fc44078c8`): the term is not recognized as the name...

How to wrap this variable into string?

Comment: I'm not familiar with teamcity, but you missing quotes for the string? is that all?

Comment: @Avshalom Right, but I cannot make it like `$version = "%build.vcs.number%"` - this command doesn't extract parameter

Comment: `$version = "%build.vcs.number%".Substring(0,8)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. Need to use command `Out-String` like
`$hash = Out-String -InputObject %build.vcs.number%`

Comment: You got a variable *named* as `%build.vcs.number%` ? What's the use? It looks like CMD environment variable.

Comment: @vonPryz It's teamcity variable - hash of last commit in repository.